# Docker container with Cassandra exited with 137?

Tags: docker

I got Ubuntu VM droplet with 4Gb Ram, 80G+50G Storage. And i'm running single Cassandra container on docker.

For Dev,Staging n Prod i have previously created three clusters and container is exit after few hours,

Then i tried three keyspaces n it also exit the container after ~40 hours.

exit code is 137,

Does this means it needs more memory or storage ? Thanks in advance